# Does it make sense to convert sub class to parent class this way?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Student{
}

class CollegeStudent extends Student{
}
```

I have a list of CollegeStudent, and I want to convert it to a list of Student:

```
List<CollegeStudent> collegeStudents = getStudents();
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
for(CollegeStudent s : collegeStudents){
     students.add(s);
}
```

Is this the appropriate way to achieve the purpose? Is the purpose sound? The reason I want to do this is I need to create another class, which takes a list of Student as parameters, not list of CollegeStduent.

Comment: No, you already have a list of students in `collegeStudents` no need to do any conversion

Comment: If it suits your needs, then yes, you can put your homogenous list of college students into a possibly heterogeneous list of students. You can add the students more simply through `new ArrayList( collegeStudents )` or by using `students.addAll( collegeStudents )`. There's no need to iterate through the list yourself.

Comment: Please see my additions.

Comment: "I need to create another class, which takes a list of Student as parameters" <- If that method can be freely modified by you you can just declare it to accept any list of type Student or subclasses: `public void someMethod(List<? extends Student> studentList)` Then you don't need to convert your list and can just pass your List<CollegeStudent> directly.

Comment: Good idea! But I also have to define an instance variable "List<?
 extends Student> m_studentList", then "m_studentList = studentList". Does this sound good?

Comment: No you don't. You can just pass your list in.

Comment: You could declare the method to take a parameter `List<? extends Student>` and then make a defensive copy internally as in e.g. `mStudentList = new ArrayList<Student>(studentList);`. Whether it's appropriate to assign the argument directly to the private field isn't something we can say for sure without looking at all of your code. If you assign it directly then the outside world can modify your object's private state which makes it more difficult to reason about.

Comment: Good suggestions, Radiodef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fine, but there are a few shorter ways:

```
// Using the Collection<? extends E> constructor:
List<Student> studentsA = new ArrayList<>(collegeStudents);
// Using Collections.unmodifiableList which returns
// an unmodifiable view of the List<CollegeStudent>
// as a List<Student> without copying its elements:
List<Student> studentsB = Collections.unmodifiableList(collegeStudents);
// Older versions of Java might require a type
// witness for Collections.unmodifiableList:
List<Student> studentsC = Collections.<Student>unmodifiableList(collegeStudents);
```

Comment: I don't think B and C will compile.

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at the signature for `synchronizedList()`. Nice answer.